# How do I find out from my database what version of Wordpress I need?

Tags: database, backup, wordpress-version, troubleshooting

I have a Wordpress website that someone broke at some point when trying to update it. Unfortunately, I do not have a backup of the original files that the site used. What I do have is a seemingly acceptable backup of the SQL database. However, whenever I try to pair this database with some Wordpress files, I get asked to do a database update. When I do a database update, I lose parts of the website that I need. I do not know the specific way it is made, so I cannot simply remake it. I have also checked pretty thoroughly for other backups. These are the best that I have.

What I most like to know is how to find out what version of Wordpress this database belongs to. I have an approximate date of when it was made and when the backup is from, but there are still a lot of potential versions of Wordpress that it could be. And trying all of them would take a very long time.

Could someone please help me find a way to tell what version of Wordpress my database belongs to? Or does anyone have any other ideas that could help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have a db_version in a "_options" table, also there are information about installed plugins and themes.

1. With information about dates when website was disrupted you can get back to approximate versions of plugins.
2. With these assumptions you can recover the most appropriate version of WP where that version of a plugin works correctly or even was released.

I hope you understand what the logic is, and you can continue yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I do not seem to have an _otions table. I do have a wp_options table, but with no version in it. I figure that because Wordpress knows that the database needs an update that there must be a value somewhere, but it's not in those places so far as I can see.

I think that I will follow that logic. Going from the date on my database backup is my only choice.

Comment: Sorry man. You are right about 'wp_options'.
I wrote about plugin versions by which you should investigate WP version.
Your old website had had a lot of plugins I guess. And some of them or even every one made a record in database with its initial parameters and version. You have to find something similar to a plugin name, then you have to read its params (basically saved in a JSON format).
When you will get one you can find the plugin version history and its release date. You know what to do later, I mean, find WP version is actual on that date.

Comment: I ended up finding a backup that had the original website and database and everything. Thank you, though!